# Changed data after renaming fields in Django models.py

Tags: django, database, sqlite

I'm doing and playing around with my own Django project.

I tried to change a couple of names of fields in models.py and tried some ways that I found on google.

The way I did was just to change the name of the field and do make migrations on command line. Once I did it, it asked if I want to rename the original field into the new name of the field, and I just responded yes and migrate it.

But I figured out it's not working out as it had been so I checked my administration page on Django and DB Browser for SQLite and found that all data of the field I changed in the name have been also changed into the name of changed field name that I tried as shown in the picture.

(i.e. I changed field called ingredient into Essential_ingredient. However, all of its data also changed into essential_ingredient, just lowered-cased name of changed field name)

Does anyone know how to retrieve or bring back my old data?
Thanks in advance!

Picture of changed name of the field and its data in models.py:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can perform below step to get new and fresh db schema.

```
python manage.py migrate --fake myApp zero
```

then delete all migration file in every folder and see migration using below command

```
python manage.py showmigrations
```

and then do

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
```

For more info you can follow below links.
https://www.techiediaries.com/how-to-reset-migrations-in-django-17-18-19-and-110/

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html